# constraint layout coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout as my main layout. Inside it, I have a CoordinatorLayout. I want to know if ever will I be able to constrain the views I put inside the CoordinatorLayout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in the coordination layout it will work just fine! as it does in the normal coordinate layout but the answer to your question is the inner layout won't act to be constrained!
if you want an inner Constrain! you have to make it for your self inside it! like a new constraint layout container as a child of coordinate layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can only constrain views that are direct children of the `ConstraintLayout`.

It isn't specifically `CoordinatorLayout` that makes you unable to do this. Any view you put inside a `ConstraintLayout` (other than another ConstraintLayout) won't be able to apply constraints.

Any `app:layout_constraint...` attribute you apply to any view that doesn't have a `ConstraintLayout` as its immediate parent will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

you must put inside any layout on CoordinatorLayout like LinearLayout or ConstraintLayout.

or make CoordinatorLayout main and put inside layout.